# Gradle build error while importing project: "Error: The file name must end with .xml"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, import, build.gradle

I'm trying to clone a repository in Android Studio that my friend has recently pushed to GitHub. He's put a png file in the resources directory, and when I try to build it, the console says:

```
/.../app/src/main/res/picture100/empty.png: Error: The file name must end with .xml
```

I've googled a lot for a solution, but found that in most similar cases the console message reads "The file name must end with .xml or .png", so please note that in my message there is **no "or .png"**, for it is just the png file that gradle won't allow in the resources files.

I've confirmed with my friend that we're using the same version of both Gradle(4.1) and Android Plugin(3.0.0).

build.gralde:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xyzhang.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The symbol R will never be resolved for the gradle build has failed. It appears in red.

How could this issue be resolved?

Comment: did you try removing that picture100 folder and put your png in a drawable folder ?! i guess when you get it from version control the setting which indicates that the folder is a resource folder doesn't become updated or even pushed to git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/.../app/src/main/res/picture100/empty.png: Error: The file name must end with .xml
```

Seems like you have created **picture100** folder inside **res** folder. Android does not allow you to create this kind of folder inside **res** directory. So you have to remove it.

Or if you wish to continue with **picture100** folder then you must have to put `xml` files inside this folder.

You can use image files inside **drawable** or **mipmap**